# Puppeteer returns an error when I try to go to another url

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have no idea wtf is happening because I'm just trying to access another url after some element load into the page

So this is the part of my code that's giving me trouble:

```
page.goto(urlOne);

await Promise.all([
    page.waitForSelector('#email')
]);

await page.type('#email', 'email');
await page.type('#password', 'password');
await page.click('[type="submit"]');

await page.waitForSelector('.Q0LJY');

page.goto(urlTwo)
```

And catches the error:

```
                ? new Error(`${response.errorText} at ${url}`)
                  ^
```

Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at https://.../_mt70c0M
at navigate (C:\Users\MTC\Desktop\JS\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Frame.js:225:23)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Frame.goto (C:\Users\MTC\Desktop\JS\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Frame.js:195:21)
at async Page.goto (C:\Users\MTC\Desktop\JS\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\Page.js:1155:16)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your request was aborted. Maybe because the test suite already started to exit. Did you try to add an "await" to your operation? I.e.

```
await page.goto(urlTwo)
```

Comment: yeah I tried and it worked but since the page takes too long to fully load I was trying to avoid this...

Comment: Use `await page.goto(urlTwo, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"})` to speed it up. It's no slower than not awaiting it because a selector can't be visible until the dom content is loaded anyway. `Promise.all` is pointless when you only have one promise in the array, BTW. Also, does `await page.click('[type="submit"]');` trigger a navigation? You should `waitForNavigation` along with that in a `Promise.all` if so. The code is rather odd--you wait for a selector then trigger a `goto` unconditionally, so you might want to add more context so others can see the big picture and offer clear advice.